# Perl - Detecting symbolic links under Windows 10

Tags: perl, windows-10

I have a problem with detecting symbolic links under Windows 10, which supports them. First I tried this:

```
if(! -l $import_filename) {
    print "$0: $import_filename is not a symlink";
}
```

That doesn't work. It gets executed when $import_filename is a symlink. Then I tried this:

```
use File::stat;
use Fcntl;

my $statbuf = lstat($import_filename);
if(!($statbuf->mode & S_ISLNK)) {
    print "$0: $import_filename is not a symlink";
}
```

And it seems to be a different way to say the same thing. As expected, is there any blessed way to do this under Windows versions with symlink/junction support? If there isn't, a command line tool is also an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given

```
>mklink file_symlink file
symbolic link created for file_symlink <<===>> file

>mklink /d dir_symlink dir
symbolic link created for dir_symlink <<===>> dir

>mklink /h file_hardlink file
Hardlink created for file_hardlink <<===>> file

>mklink /j dir_hardlink dir
Junction created for dir_hardlink <<===>> dir

>dir
...
2018-05-09  12:59 AM    <JUNCTION>     dir_hardlink [C:\...\dir]
2018-05-09  12:58 AM    <SYMLINKD>     dir_symlink [dir]
2018-05-09  12:56 AM                 6 file_hardlink
2018-05-09  12:58 AM    <SYMLINK>      file_symlink [file]
...
```

You can use the following to detect `file_symlink`, `dir_symlink` and `dir_hardlink` (but not `file_hardlink`) as a link:

```
use Win32API::File qw( GetFileAttributes FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT );

my $is_link = GetFileAttributes($qfn) & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT;
```

I don't know how to distinguish between hard links and symlinks (though differentiating between files and dirs can be done using `& FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY`).

Comment: FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT can be other things than links, you need to also obtain the reparse point data and check if it is actually a symbolic link. So that $is_link code is, to the best of my knowledge, wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be not much Perl support for working with symlinks on Windows (if any). Neither of related builtins are implemented, according to [perlport](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html) page [for symlink](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html#readlink) and [for readlink](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html#readlink).

Most importantly for your direct question, [lstat isn't implemented](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html#-X) either so one can't have a filetest for symlink. The [perlport for -X](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html#-X) says that

> `-g`, `-k`, `-l`, `-u`, `-A` are not particularly meaningful.

I haven't found anything on CPAN, other than using the Windows API.

---

Then you can go to the Windows command line, and look for `<SYMLINK>` in `dir` output

```
# Build $basename and $path from $import_filename if needed
if ( not grep { /<SYMLINK>.*$basename/ } qx(dir $path) ) {
    say "$0: $import_filename is not a symlink";
}
```

where `$basename` need be used since `dir` doesn't show the path. The components of a filename with full path can be obtained for example with the core module [File::Spec](https://perldoc.perl.org/File/Spec.html)

```
use File::Spec;
my ($vol, $path, $basename) = File::Spec->splitpath($import_filename);
```

If the filename has no path then `$vol` and `$path` are empty strings, which is OK for `dir` as it needs no argument for the current directory.  If `$import_filename` by design refers to the current directory (has no path) then use it in the regex, with `qx(dir)` (no argument).

The `dir` output shows the target name as well, what can come in handy.

Comment: @ikegami Ah ... thank you. That's completely wrong then, removed it.