# How to determine if two handles refer to the same file

Tags: perl, handler, stat, filehandler

I would like to check if two file handles refer to the same file. In order to do this, can I use the `stat` function applied to each file handle?
Thanks in advance

```
my $file = 'C:\temp\file.txt');
open( TXT1, "> $file" );
open( TXT2, "> $file" );
print( "The handles refer to the same file!") if (\TXT1 eq \TXT2);
```

Comment: If you are on a filesystem that supports it, you can compare the `dev` and `ino` values from stat. However, your filename indicates you're on Windows, where these values are not meaningful.

Comment: Can't do that in general.  An existing filehandle need not be associated with a file at all; could be a socket/pipe/etc.  Can you change how the files are opened in that program?  Then you can add a hash to keep track of them using `fileno` for instance

Comment: Note: it is not filehandle**R** (with "r" at the end), it is filehandle (no "r").  It's a handle -- something associated with a file and given to us, so that we can handle the file.

Comment: Seconding @zdim's advice to use lexical filehandles, three-arg open, and error handling. The [File::Open](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Open) module can wrap all of this up nicely for you, as well as modules like [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny).

Comment: @zdim, It's called a handle because it allows us to hold onto a system resource.

Comment: @ikegami Eh, I guess that's right.  I like to think of a "handle" being something that allows me to ... handle the thing. But I guess it allows me to hold it  .. um ... little circular

Answer (score 4):

That can't be done in general (portably),<sup>†</sup> what is understandable given that a "file"handle need not be associated with a file at all.  One thing you can do is to record the [fileno](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fileno.html) for each filehandle.

So when opening a file

```
my %filename_fileno;

open my $fh, '>', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";

$filename_fileno{fileno $fh} = $file;
```

and then you can look it up when needed <sup>‡</sup>

```
say "Filename is: ", $filename_fileno{fileno $fh};
```

Don't forget to remove the entry from the hash when that file is (to be) closed

```
delete $filename_fileno{fileno $fh};
close $fh;
```

So these should be in utility functions. Given that more care is needed, as outlined in the footnote <sup>‡</sup>, altogether this would make for a nice little module. Then one can also consider to extend (inherit from) a related module, like [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny).

Note: You cannot write to a file from separate filehandles like in the question.  Operations on each filehandle keep track of where *that* filehandle was last in the file, thus writes will clobber intermediate writes by the other filehandle.

Note:  Use lexical filehandles (`my $fh`) and not globs (`FH`), use the three-argument `open`, and *always check the `open` call*.

---

<sup>†</sup>   On some (most?) Linux systems you can use `/proc` filesystem

```
say readlink("/proc/$$/fd/" . fileno $fh);
```

and on more (all?) Unix-y systems can use the (device and) inode number

```
say for (stat $fh)[0,1];
```

---

<sup>‡</sup>   Links, both soft (symbolic) and hard, can be used to change the data and have different names. So we can have different filenames but same "file" (data).

On Windows systems the best way to check is given in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50245729/4653379), except for the hardlink case for which one would have to use the other answer's method (parse output), as far as I can tell.

Also, non-canonical names, as well as different capitalizations (on case insensitive systems), short/long names on some systems, (more?) ... can make for different names for the same file. This is easier to clean up, using modules, but needs to be added as well.

On most (all?) other systems the notion of inode and any available `stat`-like functionality makes these a non-issue, since device+inode refers uniquely to data.

Thanks to [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami) for comments on this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, on some system+device combinations, `stat` can be used.

```
use File::stat;

my $st1 = stat($fh1)
   or die $!;
my $st2 = stat($fh2)
   or die $!;

say $st1->dev == $st2->dev && $st1->ino == $st2->ino ? "same" : "different";
```

Notably, this won't work on NTFS or FAT32, one of which you appear to be using.

You should have your program keep track of that itself, but that's easier said than done. It's rather hard to identify if two paths refer to the same file when you have to contend with hard links, soft links, paths with `.`/`..`, capitalization/slash differences, short/long names, conventional/UNC paths, shares, etc.

For example, all of the following paths could refer to the same file:

- `C:\Moo\Foo Bar.txt`
- `C:\Hardlink\Foo Bar.txt`
- `C:\Softlink\Foo Bar.txt`
- `C:\.\Moo\Foo Bar.txt`
- `C:\Baz\..\Moo\Foo Bar.txt`
- `c:\moo\foo bar.txt`
- `C:/Moo/Foo Bar.txt`
- `C:\Moo\FOOBAR~1.TXT`
- `\\?\C:\Moo\Foo Bar.txt`
- `\\127.0.0.1\C$\Moo\Foo Bar.txt`
- `Z:\Moo\Foo Bar.txt`

All but the last two can be handled via normalization.